# Defining variables in a php script

Tags: php, mysql, variables, post

I bought the book "PHP and MySql Web Development"(Oct 2008) and don't understand how the following code is supposed to work. This is meant to be the front page and output this: [image: http://i.imgur.com/jMBALZh.jpg?1]

But as soon as it is loaded the first time errors occur for undefined variabes. Long script, relevant section is the start where the variables are defined.

```
    <?php
// This file is the main body of the Warm Mail application.
// It works basically as a state machine and shows users the
// output for the action they have chosen.

//*****************************************************************************
// Stage 1: pre-processing
// Do any required processing before page header is sent
// and decide what details to show on page headers
//*****************************************************************************

  include ('include_fns.php');
  session_start();
  //create short variable names
  @$username = $_POST['username'];
  @$passwd = $_POST['passwd'];
  @$action = $_REQUEST['action'];
  @$account = $_REQUEST['account'];
  @$messageid = $_GET['messageid'];

  @$to =  $_POST['to'];
  @$cc =  $_POST['cc'];
  @$subject =  $_POST['subject'];
  @$message =  $_POST['message'];

  @$buttons = array();

  //append to this string if anything processed before header has output
  $status = '';

  // need to process log in or out requests before anything else
  if ($username || $password) {
    if(login($username, $passwd)) {
      $status .= "<p style=\"padding-bottom: 100px\">Logged in successfully.</p>";
      $_SESSION['auth_user'] = $username;
      if(number_of_accounts($_SESSION['auth_user'])==1) {
        $accounts = get_account_list($_SESSION['auth_user']);
        $_SESSION['selected_account'] = $accounts[0];
      }
    } else {
      $status .= "<p style=\"padding-bottom: 100px\">Sorry, we could not log you in with that
                  username and password.</p>";
    }
  }

  if($action == 'log-out') {
    session_destroy();
    unset($action);
    $_SESSION=array();
  }

  //need to process choose, delete or store account before drawing header
  switch ($action) {
    case 'delete-account':
      delete_account($_SESSION['auth_user'], $account);
    break;

    case 'store-settings':
      store_account_settings($_SESSION['auth_user'], $_POST);
    break;

    case 'select-account':
      // if have chosen a valid account, store it as a session variable
      if(($account) && (account_exists($_SESSION['auth_user'], $account))) {
        $_SESSION['selected_account'] = $account;
      }
    break;
  }

  // set the buttons that will be on the tool bar
  $buttons[0] = 'view-mailbox';
  $buttons[1] = 'new-message';
  $buttons[2] = 'account-setup';

  //only offer a log out button if logged in
  if(check_auth_user()) {
    $buttons[4] = 'log-out';
  }

//*****************************************************************************
// Stage 2: headers
// Send the HTML headers and menu bar appropriate to current action
//*****************************************************************************
  if($action) {
    // display header with application name and description of page or action
    do_html_header($_SESSION['auth_user'], "Warm Mail - ".
                   format_action($action),
                   $_SESSION['selected_account']);
  } else {
    // display header with just application name
    do_html_header($_SESSION['auth_user'], "Warm Mail",
                   $_SESSION['selected_account']);
  }

  display_toolbar($buttons);

//*****************************************************************************
// Stage 3: body
// Depending on action, show appropriate main body content
//*****************************************************************************
  //display any text generated by functions called before header
  echo $status;

  if(!check_auth_user()) {
    echo "<p>You need to log in";

    if(($action) && ($action!='log-out')) {
      echo " to go to ".format_action($action);
    }
    echo ".</p>";
    display_login_form($action);
  } else {
    switch ($action) {
      // if we have chosen to setup a new account, or have just added or
      // deleted an account, show account setup page
      case 'store-settings':

      case 'account-setup':

      case 'delete-account':
        display_account_setup($_SESSION['auth_user']);
      break;

      case 'send-message':
        if(send_message($to, $cc, $subject, $message)) {
          echo "<p style=\"padding-bottom: 100px\">Message sent.</p>";
        } else {
          echo "<p style=\"padding-bottom: 100px\">Could not send message.</p>";
        }
      break;

      case 'delete':
         delete_message($_SESSION['auth_user'],
                        $_SESSION['selected_account'], $messageid);
         //note deliberately no 'break' - we will continue to the next case

      case 'select-account':

      case 'view-mailbox':
        // if mailbox just chosen, or view mailbox chosen, show mailbox
        display_list($_SESSION['auth_user'],
                    $_SESSION['selected_account']);
      break;

      case 'show-headers':
      case 'hide-headers':
      case 'view-message':
        // if we have just picked a message from the list, or were looking at
        // a message and chose to hide or view headers, load a message
        $fullheaders = ($action == 'show-headers');
        display_message($_SESSION['auth_user'],
                        $_SESSION['selected_account'],
                        $messageid, $fullheaders);
      break;

      case 'reply-all':
        //set cc as old cc line
        if(!$imap) {
          $imap = open_mailbox($_SESSION['auth_user'],
                               $_SESSION['selected_account']);
        }

        if($imap) {
          $header = imap_header($imap, $messageid);

          if($header->reply_toaddress) {
            $to = $header->reply_toaddress;
          } else {
            $to = $header->fromaddress;
          }

          $cc = $header->ccaddress;
          $subject = "Re: ".$header->subject;
          $body = add_quoting(stripslashes(imap_body($imap, $messageid)));
          imap_close($imap);

          display_new_message_form($_SESSION['auth_user'],
          $to, $cc, $subject, $body);
        }

      break;

      case 'reply':
        //set to address as reply-to or from of the current message
        if(!$imap) {
          $imap = open_mailbox($_SESSION['auth_user'],
                               $_SESSION['selected_account']);
        }

        if($imap) {
          $header = imap_header($imap, $messageid);
          if($header->reply_toaddress) {
            $to = $header->reply_toaddress;
          } else {
            $to = $header->fromaddress;
          }
          $subject = "Re: ".$header->subject;
          $body = add_quoting(stripslashes(imap_body($imap, $messageid)));
          imap_close($imap);

          display_new_message_form($_SESSION['auth_user'],
                                   $to, $cc, $subject, $body);
        }

      break;

      case 'forward':
        //set message as quoted body of current message
        if(!$imap) {
          $imap = open_mailbox($_SESSION['auth_user'],
                               $_SESSION['selected_account']);
        }

        if($imap) {
          $header = imap_header($imap, $messageid);
          $body = add_quoting(stripslashes(imap_body($imap, $messageid)));
          $subject = "Fwd: ".$header->subject;
          imap_close($imap);

          display_new_message_form($_SESSION['auth_user'],
                                   $to, $cc, $subject, $body);
        }
      break;

      case 'new-message':
        display_new_message_form($_SESSION['auth_user'],
                                 $to, $cc, $subject, $body);
      break;
    }
  }
//*****************************************************************************
// Stage 4: footer
//*****************************************************************************
  do_html_footer();
?>
```

I understand the errors are due to `$_POST` being empty, therefore undefined variables but why is it written like this. isthis code faulty or am I missing anything obvious. BTW, `include ('include_fns.php');` doesn't output anything, simply a list of functions.

Comment: You usually use `isset($_POST['variableName'])` to avoid these types of errors. `isset()` returns a boolean. Read more about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Comment: I can't go through all the code, but the first thing i see is that your first if statment evaluates a "$password" variable, while you declared such variable as "$passwd"

Comment: it would help to know which `variables` are undefined. Where is the form that posts these values? Is it in `include_fns.php`?

Comment: And by the way, if the above doesn't fix it, there might be multiple issues on multiple lines. If that's the case check each reported line for such errors

Comment: This doesn't come from any form. It is meant to generate the HTML further down in the script. This is literally the code lifted from the book, I was just trying to confirm that its faulty. Thanks for the "isset() advice.

Comment: Yeah I think that may be necessary. Would a 2008 book be largely outdated and have little application today?

Comment: Is there any way that you  may be persuaded to look at a more modern book on learning PHP? Any book that mentions **'mysql_*' functions** **rather** than '**mysqli_*'** or **'PDO'** database functions should be avoided at all costs.Also, the book **should** include the use of **'prepared queries'** which are rather more **'safe'**.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I guess starting session on top of EVERYTHING should be better.

Like **simpe** said, you must check your GET, POST, SESSION etc. values if they're set to anything.

If you want a better way, I suggest you to check if they're set and not empty.

For example: Think about a querystring like

```
example.com/index.php?id=16
```

isset($_GET['id']) will return TRUE. That's OK.

But what about I try to mess around:

```
example.com/index.php?id=
```

Well, it's set. But empty.

So I suggest:

```
if(isset($_POST['var']) && !empty($_POST['var']))
```

should do the trick.

Comment: I don't understand. In my example, they are different. Sometimes isset is not enough by itself. Of course in this question it might be unneccessary but I think checking value content is important.

Comment: You are correct that 'isset()' is not enough by itself when checking $thing for having a value. Your concern is that the variable $thing might not exist. **Empty($thing)** does an 'isset($thing)' check first and returns true if it does **not exist** then it checks the value of **$thing** and returns true if it has an 'empty' value. So: **!empty($thing)** when true says: it must exist and has a useful value. False means it may not exist or has no useful value. **empty()** does an **isset()** test internally. As is stated in the manual.

Comment: I see now. Thanks for your comments.